# Reclaim disk space from old Windows partition?

Tags: bootcamp, partition, core-storage

How do I reclaim the disk space used by my former Windows partition?

[Clear free space in Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169546/clear-free-space-in-disk-utility)

> So I recently removed Windows 7 from my iMac, but Bootcamp didn't let me do it. I used Disk Utility instead. The old Windows 7 partition now shows up as free space. I want to reinstall Windows 7 again on my iMac, how do I set it up? Can I use the free space again? I want to give the Windows partition a bigger size than what the free space currently holds.

I'm having the exact same issue, but mine is 70 GB of data on 250 GB flash drive. I too am running OS X 10.10, Yosemite.

The accepted answer to the question above says restore the computer, but I don't want to lose my data or buy a Time Machine drive. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I installed the [Windows 10 Preview](https://insider.windows.com).
- I then booted up into OS X.
- I turned off FileVault, and removed my Windows partition via [Boot Camp Assistant](https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/).

Finally, check disk utility and you'll see the free space went to your Mac partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using High Sierra and APFS. Try this.

Below command to find the list of Drives.

```
diskutil list
```

run this to retrieve the the free space.

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Now your unused free space will be added to your existing hard disk as a single partition.

Answer (score -2):

The only correct way is indeed to use Bootcamp Assistant to free up the Windows partition space...